# OpenNebula 4,14.2 Federation error VNC Master/Slave

Tags: cloud, vnc, vnc-server, federated, opennebula

We have federated two OpenNebula as master/slave, but we have detected a strange issue. Using the Master Sunstone, we can change to the Slave Sunstone. It works well, but if we try to lunch the VNC console from any virtual machine it fails (slave side). If we login directly in the slave Sunstone we do not have any problem and reverse slave change master.

We are using OpenNebula version 4.14. We do not see any error in the logs. We do not have connectivity issues.

About the federation I do not understand how to solve. Could you explain? 
`-Federation Master-> Slave Failed to connect to VNC server (code: 1006)`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [ticket](http://dev.opennebula.org/issues/4308). It is not supported yet, since it needs some logic in the NoVNC server to forward request to the target Sunstone. The only workaround right now is to login directly in the Sunstone Slave.